# With pen and paper, digits that follow the first occurrence of a sequence in pi

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math, puzzle, pi

Let's suppose that we know where the first occurrence of a sequence of n digits appears in the number pi decimal section. For example, the first occurrence of the sequence 26091955 appears in the decimal position 107,607,919.

Is there any way to calculate manually (pen and paper) the decimal digits that would follow? (in the example, it'd be 25916325541684811916)

Comment: @Arthur What you say is correct, but it's not what was asked. We *do* know that the given sequence appears.

Comment: @Arthur: That's probably why the question begins with "Let's suppose".

Comment: So, what you're really after is a pen and paper algorithm for finding a given digit of $\pi$? What's the role of the given sequence?

Comment: @Arthur No, I'm not after an algorithm for finding a given digit. I believe the question covers pretty well what I want to do, and requires assuming that the given sequence is the first occurrence of that sequence. I'm trying to add a puzzle to a book, and I'm wondering if there's a "pen and paper" way of doing this.

Comment: But what you're after in the example (finding the sequence 25916325541684811916) is essentially finding decimals number 107,607,927 through 107,607,946, it's just that we're given the additional information that 26091955 precedes it. At least that's how I see it.